# Make a post HTTP

Tags: flutter

I follow the below code, but it seems not to work:

```
var body = jsonEncode(<String, String>{
  'uid': uid,
  'limit': '10',
  'offset': '2',
  'action': 'feed',
});

final response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse('http://abc.or/fb/selectPosts.php'),
  body: body,
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  List<Post> posts = [];
  // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
  // then parse the JSON.
  print((jsonDecode(response.body)));
  return List<Post>.from(jsonDecode(response.body));
} else {
  // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
  // then throw an exception.
  throw Exception('Failed to update album.');
}
```

My API looks like this: `http:/abc.or/fb/post.php?uid=aaaa&limit=10&offset=2&action=feed`

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
...
static const urlPrefix = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
...


Future<void> makePostRequest() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('$urlPrefix/posts');
    final headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
    final json = '{"title": "Hello", "body": "body text", "userId": 1}';
    final response = await post(url, headers: headers, body: json);
    print('Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('Body: ${response.body}');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are query fields not request body fields.
They are passed in the link or as queryparematers in a Uri

```dart
final response = await http.get(
   Uri(
   path: <your url without the queries(http://abc)>,
   query: <Your queries as they are in the string (uid=aaaa&limit=10&offset=2&action=feed), you can use string interpolation to fix the values in or better still use queryparematers, not both>
   queryParameters : <String, dynamic>{ 'uid': uid, 'limit': 10, 'offset': 2, 'action': feed },)
);
```

I use a get method which should be the standard for such url. Do confirm from whoever wrote the api if it is a uses a get or post method.